# multiplying column based on matching of second column in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, multiple-columns, text-processing

I have two files. The first file has total number of machines with particuar cpu type. It has two columns.  This is how it looks.

```
  5 custom
  3 n1-highcpu-32
  3 n1-highcpu-4
 11 n1-highmem-16
 17 n1-standard-1
  9 n1-standard-16
 27 n1-standard-2
 13 n1-standard-4
  5 n1-standard-8
```

The second file has the cost/month for each cpu type. It has this format:

```
n1-standard-1   25
n1-standard-2   49
n1-standard-4   97
n1-standard-8   194
n1-standard-16  388
n1-standard-32  777
n1-standard-64  1553
n1-highmem-2    60
n1-highmem-4    121
n1-highmem-8    242
n1-highmem-16   484
n1-highcpu-4    72
n1-highcpu-32   580
custom      53
```

To caluclate the overall effective cost , I need to take each variable from the second column of the first file and multiply it with its corresponding price from the second file.

once this is acheived , we need to add the individual prices to arrive at a total cost .

Comment: Cool. What have you tried? What problem do you have? What is the output you have? What is expected output you want to have? You can find someone who will do the job for you at freelancing sites. This looks pretty simple - use join to merge files and datamesh or awk to calculate. You can read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: May I recommend a database?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{cost[$1]=$2;next}{sum=$1*cost[$2];print $2,sum;total+=sum}END{print total}' file2 file1
```

Comment: When you post next time, please show what part of your code your are having issues from.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl Oneliner

```
> cat santhu1
  5 custom
  3 n1-highcpu-32
  3 n1-highcpu-4
 11 n1-highmem-16
 17 n1-standard-1
  9 n1-standard-16
 27 n1-standard-2
 13 n1-standard-4
  5 n1-standard-8
> cat santhu2
n1-standard-1   25
n1-standard-2   49
n1-standard-4   97
n1-standard-8   194
n1-standard-16  388
n1-standard-32  777
n1-standard-64  1553
n1-highmem-2    60
n1-highmem-4    121
n1-highmem-8    242
n1-highmem-16   484
n1-highcpu-4    72
n1-highcpu-32   580
custom      53
> perl -lane 'BEGIN {%kv=map split(/\s+/),qx(cat santhu2)} { print $F[0]*$kv{$F[1]}," ",$F[1] }' santhu1
265 custom
1740 n1-highcpu-32
216 n1-highcpu-4
5324 n1-highmem-16
425 n1-standard-1
3492 n1-standard-16
1323 n1-standard-2
1261 n1-standard-4
970 n1-standard-8
>
```